# API: use HTTP headers to control business flow

Tags: rest, api, architecture

I've just heard that using HTTP headers to control business flow is bad practice. Could someone give me an explanation why?

In my case, the default response contains only simple information but if you add `X-Full-Info` header there will be more information but request processing will take more time. Why is it bad practice? I was suggested to use query parameter.

Comment: Why are you using a custom http header here rather than doing it in a RESTful style and using the standard accept / content headers to control the amount of returned data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One reason is caching.  Assuming you are using GET, the result may be cached, and your http header will be ignored if the result is served from a cache.  (Either a remote cache or your browser’s cache)

But if you use a query parameter to choose the results, the cache will know which result to return, and won’t return the wrong result.

You can try to solve this using the “Vary” header, but support for that header means more work on your part, and support for that header is not as widespread: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2009/06/17/vary-with-care/

Comment: The server could set the `Vary` header with the value "X-Full-Info" to solve this particular issue. But I do agree using a proper URI is better.

Comment: @RobertBräutigam I added some more information in my answer.  (Though, I forgot to log in at the time)  Hopefully that helps.